# C# - write a program that displays the calendar, asking just for the year and month, use System.DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, system

I am stuck on this, i need help on how i can ask for user input to enter any year and any month, then that will output a monthly calendar for that specified year and month, i also need to use system.datetime
This is the code i have so far and i dont think it is correct, any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
class Program
{
    static int year = new int();
    static int month = new int();
    static int[,] calendar = new int[6, 7];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the year? ");
        year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter the month (January = 1, etc): ");
        month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        DrawHeader();
        FillCalendar();
        DrawCalendar();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void DrawHeader()
    {
        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + month);
        Console.WriteLine("Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su");
    }

    static void FillCalendar()
    {
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        int currentDay = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < calendar.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < calendar.GetLength(1) && currentDay <= days; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 && month > j)
                {
                    calendar[i, j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    calendar[i, j] = currentDay;
                    currentDay++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void DrawCalendar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < calendar.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < calendar.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (calendar[i, j] > 0)
                {
                    if (calendar[i, j] < 10)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" " + calendar[i, j] + " ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(calendar[i, j] + " ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("   ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you describe a little more in detail why you think that it is not correct? or what exact problems you encountered?

Comment: What do you mean you have to use System.DateTime, what do you have to use it for? E.g. do you need to convert the values entered into a date object?

Comment: yh, its not correct in the sense that the output isnt what its suppose to do, for example i need to use system.datetime and i havent as i dont know how i can implement that

Comment: you should look up System.DateTime on the Microsoft Development
Network library. You can declare a variable of type DateTime and then assign a new
DateTime object to it created using the entered year and month. From that, you can
use the methods and properties of DateTime to determine the starting day, the number
of days in the month, etc.

Comment: this is why i need to use system.datetime

Comment: You should take the weekday into account. Right now it claims that today (1st of December of 2016) is a Monday. It isn't, it is a Thursday.

Comment: so what can i do to fix it correctly?

Comment: the algorithm always starts from 0 in every month

Comment: what do i need to do exactly, im sorry if i sound a bit stupid it is because i am a beginner

Comment: Think about it logically. Forget that it is a program. There is a DayOfWeek property for a given date (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx). How would you use that to put day #1 in its proper place on the first row of the 2x2 matrix? If you can explain someone how you did that, then after that you can also program it.

Comment: i should check if the start date of any month is in weekday, i.e monday to friday so it can be outputted correctly

Comment: so 1st of every month needs a weekday check?? of any year

Comment: is that correct how i explained it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should ensure that the day of the month is correctly aligned with the day of the week (i.e. December 1st is a Tuesday)

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Calendar
{
class Program
{
    static int year = new int();
    static int month = new int();
    static int[,] calendar = new int[6, 7];
    private static DateTime date;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the year? ");
        year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter the month (January = 1, etc): ");
        month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);//gives you a datetime object for the first day of the month
        DrawHeader();
        FillCalendar();
        DrawCalendar();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void DrawHeader()
    {
        Console.Write("\n\n");
        //gives you the month and year at the top of the calendar
        Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month) + " " + year);
        Console.WriteLine("Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su");
    }

    static void FillCalendar()
    {
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        int currentDay = 1;
        var dayOfWeek = (int) date.DayOfWeek;
        for (int i = 0; i < calendar.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < calendar.GetLength(1) && currentDay - dayOfWeek + 1 <= days; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 && month > j)
                {
                    calendar[i, j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    calendar[i, j] = currentDay - dayOfWeek + 1;
                    currentDay++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void DrawCalendar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < calendar.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < calendar.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (calendar[i, j] > 0)
                {
                    if (calendar[i, j] < 10)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" " + calendar[i, j] + " ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(calendar[i, j] + " ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("   ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

}

EDIT

If you want to get all the all the dates for a particular day of the week in a chosen month you can do something like this;

```
        var weekDay = 0;
        var dates = new List<DateTime>();
        for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
        {
            if ((int)date.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek == weekDay)
            {
                dates.Add(date.AddDays(i));
            }
        }
```

You would have to ask the user to enter a day of the week and set weekDay to the value they enter. Just remember that Sunday is 0 and Saturday = 6. (I haven't fully tested this though so be careful) - This would have to be entered into your FillCalendar method.

Comment: ok thank you so much for the help, let me see if its what i am after

Comment: Like the orignal, this claims that today (1st of December of 2016) is a Monday. It isn't, because today is Thursday.

Comment: the dates arent showing correct on this, for example if i use 2016 and November the dates are wrong and for december too, how can i fix this

Comment: on here the ouput shows monday 1st november 2016 but it should be tuesday 1st november 2016 as an example

Comment: The comparison of `month > j` makes totally no sense, and it should be removed. Instead there should be a Weekday-check in there somewhere.

Comment: i will remove it but what do i need to include instead of that?

Comment: how can i include a weekday check

Comment: I understand your issue, I'm working on it and I'll update my answer once I've figured it out

Comment: @J.Doe I've edited my answer. I think it does what you want now

Comment: let me check, thanks for the help, i appreciate it

Comment: it works, thank you so much!!!!

Comment: could i ask you one last thing if you dont mind???

Comment: Go ahead, I'll try and improve my answer to help

Comment: no no the answer for this is literally perfect, i had another query, im unsure how i can get to display a list of mondays or any other days for a specific month based on user input

Comment: for example if i type in november and monday and it should display all the mondays in november

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: I've added to my answer to try to help with your secondary problem. Any further help should probably be put into a new question. Good luck.

Comment: thanks so much,!!!!

Comment: Your welcome, remember to up-vote answers that you find helpful, it encourages us to keep answering! (But only if they are helpful!)

Comment: they were more than helpful, thank you so much, do u have an email i can contact you on please?

Comment: i sent an email

Comment: Fill calendar method should be 
static void FillCalendar()
  {
   int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
   int currentDay = 1;
   var dayOfWeek = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
   for (int i = 0; i < calendar.GetLength(0); i++)
   {
    for (int j = 0; j < calendar.GetLength(1) && currentDay <= days; j++)
    {
     if (i == 0 && dayOfWeek - 1 > j)
     {
      calendar[i, j] = 0;
     }
     else
     {
      calendar[i, j] = currentDay;
      currentDay++;
     }
    }
   }
  }